# Can't write large files to flash drive

Tags: 14.04, usb, flash

I`m having a problem copying files to any USB flash drive formatted in FAT32. Small files copy ok. But if I try to copy a large file (say 1GB) it starts to copy, the progress bar continues to grow until very near the end and then stalls permanently. I waited more than 1/2 hour and the window was blocked. I tried to close it and nothing happend. If I kill the process, the copied file is corrupt. This happens to any flash drive I use. I tested the flash drive in other computer and the files copied correctly. Anyone knows something about this ?

Answer (score 0):

There can be a noticeable mismatch when files are being transferred to a USB device and their apparent progress as it's shown on-screen. If your USB drive has an indicator light, check that it has actually stopped flashing or otherwise indicates that the transfer is complete.

One way I've found to ensure large files are transferred is to use eject option for that drive. Your computer should verify and push any remaining data that is being transferred then indicate that it's safe to remove. Watch for the notice on your screen.

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: See my edited question to clarify this. It's not a waiting question. The copy hangs permamently.

Comment: This seems to be an ongoing bug with USB devices and large files, you're certainly not the only one with this problem apparently. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/992968

Comment: Does this happens with 14.04 LTS ? And on Mint ?

Comment: Yes, most likely. I've used both Mint and I'm on 14.04, and I've never encountered this problem on my machine, so it is possibly a thing between the USB drivers and your particular hardware.